# Is it safe to do a ToTensor() data transform before a ColorJitter and RandomHorizotnalFlip and other data augmentation techniques in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I am seeing that the ToTensor is always at the end https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/imagenet/main.py:

```
        train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(
            traindir,
            transforms.Compose([
                transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
                transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                normalize,
            ]))

        val_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(
            valdir,
            transforms.Compose([
                transforms.Resize(256),
                transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                normalize,
            ]))
```

other for mini-imagenet:

```
        train_data_transform = Compose([
            # ToPILImage(),
            RandomCrop(size, padding=8),
            # decided 8 due to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/116201/when-to-use-padding-when-randomly-cropping-images-in-deep-learning
            ColorJitter(brightness=0.4, contrast=0.4, saturation=0.4),
            RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            ToTensor(),
            normalize,
        ])
        test_data_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize((size, size)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=mean,
                                 std=std),
        ])
        validation_data_transform = test_data_transform
```

is there a reason for this? What happens if we do the ToTensor (or ToTensor and Normalize) first?

Answer (score 5):

One reason why people usually use PIL format instead of tensor to perform image preprocessing is related to the resizing algorithms and especially downsizing. As pointed out in [this paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2022/papers/Parmar_On_Aliased_Resizing_and_Surprising_Subtleties_in_GAN_Evaluation_CVPR_2022_paper.pdf),

> The Lanczos, bicubic, and bilinear implementations by PIL (top row) adjust the antialiasing filter width by the downsampling factor (marked as ). Other implementations (including those used for PyTorch-FID and TensorFlow-FID) use fixed filter widths, introducing aliasing artifacts and resemble naive nearest subsampling.

[image]

image source: [clean-fid official github repo](https://github.com/GaParmar/clean-fid)

Despite that `torchvision.transforms.Resize` now supports `antialias` option, as per the documentation, it is only reducing the gap between the tensor outputs and PIL outputs to some extent. Another reason may be related to the reproducibility and portability, i.e. to have a universal preprocessing pipeline.

Comment: Great answer! What would a stanfard/safe way to do it (e.g. safest choice of interpolation and antialiasing)? My guess is to 1. always make sure its a PIL 2. at the very end do toTensor. e.g. using https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop.html which seems to be the common choice.

Comment: what do you think it means that I don't have to explicitly convert to PIL in my compose?

Comment: ImageFolder by default use PIL to open an image. Once all the preprocessing/augmentations are done, I think it is safe to convert it to Tensor by adding `ToTensor` to the end of `Compose`.